# how to get current url from UI Router - State?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

By conditionally, I require to `route` my application to a new path. so I would like to know the current `url` of my application.

how can i get my current url from sate like `toState.name`?

here is my scenario:

```
.state('serialCreateCase', {
        url: '/sn={serialNumber}', //sn=12345;
        templateUrl:'app/createCase/create-case.html',
        controller: 'createCaseController as ctrl',
        data: {
          requireLogin: false
        }
```

here is the condition:

```
if(toState.name==="serialCreateCase"){ // i am getting proper result
          console.log('toState.name', toState );
          $rootScope.goToView("serialCreateCase");  //i am asking to go there. but not works! //sn=12345;
          event.preventDefault();
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the current url or to go to another view ? Show us the `goToView()` method. What do you mean by "not working" ?

Comment: I want to take this to current url, `//sn=12345;` - whenever the user types above url

Comment: $location.path() from the controller should access the url.

Comment: I am calling this function on `$stateChangeStart` - @rr - the problem is i don't know the number what will be. so how can i redirect the number in `{serialNumber}' here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the url because you are using `states`

You should use this method

```
$state.go("serialCreateCase", {sn: 12345});
```

This will send the user to state `serialCreateCase` with the data

```
Key : sn
Value : 12345
```

**EDIT**

You code inside the controller should look like this

```
if (toState.name === "serialCreateCase") { // i am getting proper result
    console.log('toState.name', toState);
    $state.go("serialCreateCase", { sn: 12345 });
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your answer, can you update from my code? here I don't know the serial number what user will enter

Comment: Where is your code written ? Inside the controller ? On a button click ?

Comment: in side a controllers with `stateChangeStart`, when the user type any number, I would like to send them there

Comment: @3gwebtrain I updated the answer. When user type inside an input ?

Comment: no, I am calling from other application like this : 'xyz/sn=1234' - here the number I don't know. the number is dynamic here

Comment: I don't understand what you want..Can you edit your question and add clearly step by step your goal ? On which page are you ? What is the user action ? What should happend ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125875/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-weedoze).

Answer (score 0):

Edited Code:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    var curentpath = fromState.url;
    var split = curentpath.split(':');
    var params = $stateParams.sn;

    var mainUrl = split[0] +params;
    console.log(mainUrl);
  });
```

&& Route:

```
.state('serialCreateCase', {
        url: '/sn={serialNumber}', //sn=12345;
        templateUrl:'app/createCase/create-case.html',
        controller: 'createCaseController as ctrl',
        data: {
          requireLogin: false
        }
```

Comment: this is happening on `stateChangeStart ` -

Comment: at present i am putting  as `http://localhost:3000/sn=2345`, I am getting as :`{
  "name": "",
  "url": "^",
  "views": null,
  "abstract": true
}`

Comment: @3gwebtrain, Please check the following code, If this is helpful for you. Actually I couldn't understand you exact problem, But I try to myself to help you.